# Tradeoffs with client vs server side postback handling

Tags: asp.net, jquery, postback

I have a ListView that contains a large collection of rows with textboxes that users can optionally fill out.  These textboxes are not databound.  When the user clicks "next" i need to iterate over the rows and determine which fields the user has filled out, and then update a sort of "cart" with the data and move to a confirmation page ("you have selected a, g, v, zz, is this correct?" sort of thing).

1. I can think of two ways to deal with this.  The first is, server side, to walk the items in the listview, get the control ID's, save this data to a list, then save it to a database cart table for the next screen to read.
2. I can use jquery to collect all the values client side, then pass it back to the form in a hidden field and use something like Newton.Json to get the data into a similar list.

What are the tradoffs of these two approaches?  And can you think of a better way to do it?

Keep in mind that i'm on a very tight deadline, so need to do the option that i can implement the fastest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say both are equally fast to implement, at least to me.

Do what you feel most comfortable with, and it looks to me that option 1 is something you know how to do, so that would probably be your choice if time is of essence.

Performance wise the an ajax call in option 2 sends less data compared to the viewstate in option 1.

If the number of fields are not too high, I don't think either solution is a trade-off. It's more a matter of where do you put your logic, and are you comfortable with putting it on the client.

Comment: Ok, what bout stability of the Javascript and compatibility across browsers.  Obviously, I won't be supporting Lynx or anything here, but should this simple Javascript work across all browsers going back to at least IE6?  Possibly even IE5?

Comment: jQuery states IE6+, so not sure if it would work on IE5. You could always write the javascript yourself. IE4 supported xml-http requests, so you should be able to get it to work.. but.. then there's the time issue ;)

Comment: I'm not doing asynchronous postback here, no need for it.  Just collecting the results and stuffing it in a hidden field for postback processing.

Comment: After reading the above comments, I will suggest to go with the server-side option as it won't have any browser or client-side dependencies and secondly as Mikael stated option 1 looks to be quite known to you so would take less time.
May be you can try the client-side option later. :)

Comment: Regarding you latest comment:
Then client-side approach won't make much difference in request size, so better to go with option 1.

Comment: Agree, since it's a normal postback and not async.